# git commands not working in git bash (windows 7 x64)

Tags: git, windows-7, installation

I follow the help on 
http://help.github.com/win-set-up-git/
for installing git (msysgit) on windows 7 x64.

Everything went good until setting up my account.

But as soon as I tried `git config --global user.name ......` the git bash always shows me the usage of git, in short the help.
Every command (`status`, `--version`, `diff`, `help`, `status`, ...) shows the same message :
`usage: git [--version] [--exec-path.......] ...`.

`ssh` is working well because I could param the ssh key.
if I type "sit" with a mistake in git : command not found

thanks for your help.
I think that I may have missed an option in the installation.

Comment: Can you paste whats in ~/.gitconfig?

Comment: [core]
 symlinks = false
 autocrlf = true
[color]
 diff = auto
 status = auto
 branch = auto
 interactive = true
[pack]
 packSizeLimit = 2g
[help]
 format = html
[http]
 sslCAinfo = /bin/curl-ca-bundle.crt
[sendemail]
 smtpserver = /bin/msmtp.exe

[diff "astextplain"]
 textconv = astextplain
[rebase]
 autosquash = true

Comment: The entries from git config ... go into ~/.gitconfig, since you dont have this, I'm assuming things are not configured properly. Can you download git extensions and that gives you a sort of ui option of configuring things?

Answer (score 1):

> I follow the help for installing git (msysgit) on windows 7 x64.

You shouldnt be installing **msysgit** unless you are developing Git.

You should be installing **Git for Windows**.

### [code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list?q=windows+installer](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list?q=windows+installer)